# External Facebook connect site using multi friend invite, looses existing cakephp session

Tags: cakephp, facebook

I have a facebook connect site.  I am able to "login" to my site with the facebook api & fbml.  I would like to give my users the ability to invite friends.  I am using the multi invite and the form shows up fine.

My problem is once the user either invites or cancels on the page, the request back to my application from facebook, causes a new session to be started.

In the appcontroller's beforeFilter, I have tried to use the facebook session id as my cakephp application's session id, and on return from facebook, use session_id($id) to force to use the user's existing session.  However, when session_start() is finally called, a new session id is assigned every time.

Anyone out there implemented cakephp connect website that uses the multi invite.

Note:  this is an external application website, no canvas page wanted.

Comment: this is in our dev environment, so I think the setting is either low or medium, I'll take a look after the holidays.

also, my cakephp session is set to auto starting.

I have parked this issue for now on our site, going to work on other facebook functionality.

Answer (score 0):

shot in the dark, but what's your security setting?  if it's high, try medium.  then perhaps your session key won't reset on a subsequent page load.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but I fix the same issue putting security in low